# UICollectionView from thumbnail to Full Screen when tap Photo

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a series of thumbnails.
When I tap on a picture I want that it becomes full screen as happens in Photos App.
How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UICollectionView's` `delegate` method:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //get UIImage from source 
  //show (add subView) UIImageView with full screen frame
  //add gesture for double tap on which remove UIImageView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a UITapGestureRecognizer to each cell, and in the action callback method i show a new UIImageView on top of the pressed cell, but with a full sized image in, which i then animate to fill the entire screen.

That way you only have to keep thumbnails in memory, but when a user clicks a thumbnail it immediately animates into the full sized image.